# Kann „meist“ eine nicht auf Zeit sich beziehende Häufigkeit ausdrücken? Unterschied zwischen „meisten“, „meist“ und „meistens“?

Tags: adverb

(*Das ist ein Edit zur unten stehenden ursprünglichen Frage, die eigentlich zu ignorieren ist. Die echte Frage stehet über der Linie.*)

- Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *meist* und *die meisten*?
- Können beide unter Umständen Synonyme sein?
- Wenn nicht, warum sind diese Wörter so ähnlich? Haben die einen gemeinsamen Ursprung?
- Kann *meist* auch nicht auf Zeit sich beziehende Häufigkeit andeuten?

---

(*Das ist die Originalfrage:*)

Im realistischen Szenario ist die Antwort trivial: Deutschland. Jetzt nehmen wir aber an, dass die Schweiz 30 Mal die heutige Bevölkerung hätte.

**Fragen**: *Wie wäre denn die Antwort nun auf dieselbe Frage?*

> - Deutschland, weil der Anteil an Deutschsprachigen immer noch dort höher als die in der Schweiz ist.
> - Die Schweiz, weil es dort die absolute Zahl Deutschsprachiger größer als in Deutschland wäre.

- *Durch welchen Adverbien kann* meist *in der Frage ersetzt werden, damit man beide Antworten bekommt?*

Comment: Is this some kind of a riddle?

Comment: Schwer zu sagen, da die Frage grammatisch falsch ist.

Comment: na ja, stimmt, die macht keinen Sinn. Ich schließe die

Comment: Die Frage ist schon grammatikalisch korrekt, allerdings nicht mit der angestrebten Bedeutung "das Land mit den meisten Deutschsprachlern", sondern mit der Bedeutung "das Land, wo in aller Regel Deutsch gesprochen wird". Und da sind [mehrere Antworten möglich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_where_German_is_an_official_language).

Comment: @c.p. nooooooooo. Warum solltest du diese Frage schließen lassen?? Du kannst deine Frage editieren!!! In den Kommentaren hast du angedeutet, dass du die Verwendung von *"meist"* in diesem Kontext nicht verstehst.. dann formuliere die Frage neu! Du solltest nich einfach sagen:"macht keinen Sinn.", denn das stimmt nicht.

Comment: Ich hab jetzt vorläufig fürs Close zugestimmt, einfach weil die Frage so wie sie jetzt steht, tatsächlich immer noch nicht klar stellt, WAS das Problem ist. Ich glaube anhand der Antworten das eigetnliche Problem verstanden zu haben, aber es sind nicht die Antworten, die eine Frage "gut machen". Ich stimme aber @Vogel612 zu, dass mit einigen Änderungen die Fragen "retten" kann. Das musst aber hier du selbst übernehmen, weil wenn es einer von uns macht, fällt es unter die Kategorie "radical change" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich glaube, hier liegt ein Missverständnis vor:

**Meist** heißt "in der Regel, für gewöhnlich, in der Mehrzahl der Fälle, fast immer, meistens" <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/meist)</sup>

Damit verstehe ich die genannte Frage so, dass Du "das Land, in dem in dem fast immer Deutsch gesprochen wird", suchst.

Aus Deiner Beschreibung wird allerdings deutlich, dass Du eigentlich nach dem "Land, in dem **am meisten** Deutsch gesprochen wird" fragen willst.

Und hier ist tatsächlich beides möglich - siehe die Antwort von Toscho.

Answer (score 2):

*Meist* ist eine Kurzversion von *meistens*. *Meistens* ist ein Wort, das über Zeit spricht. Es gehört mit folgenden Wörtern zusammen.

> nie, selten, oft, meistens, immer

Es heißt nicht dasselbe wie *mostly*, und auch nicht dasselbe wie *the most*.

Daher sind beide deine Antworten keine Antwort auf deine Frage. Du suchst also das Land:

> In which it is spoken German most of the time.

Wenn du wissen willst, in welchem Land "am meisten" Deutsch gesprochen wird, dann ist das nicht zu beantworten, da wir ja nicht wissen wer wieviel spricht. Vielleicht sprechen die Deutschen 10 mal weniger als die Schweizer. *Am meisten* misst eine Menge und in diesem Fall wäre es die Menge an "Deutsch"... wie soll man das zählen, oder wer zählt denn sowas.

Die Fragen für deine Antworten würde man präziser formulieren....

> Welches Land hat den höchsten Anteil an...
>
> Welches Land hat in absoluten Zahlen die meisten ...

Answer (score 1):

Die Adverbien `viel` (Positiv von `meist`) und `häufig` können sowohl die [absolute Häufigkeit](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_H%C3%A4ufigkeit) als auch die [relative Häufigkeit](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_H%C3%A4ufigkeit) bezeichnen. Es gibt kein Adverb, das ohne weitere Klarstellung einen der beiden Begriffe bezeichnet.

Den Rest deiner Frage verstehe ich nicht ganz. Auf welche der beiden Häufigkeiten beziehst du dich?